# Webkit: be notified when document.body.scrollHeight changes

Tags: javascript, webkit

Is there a way to be notified when document.body.scrollHeight changes ?
I know that I could set an interval to check it every 100ms but i'am looking for a cleaner solution.
I'm targetting mobile webkit browsers only. So I don't care about other browsers.

Comment: You don't happen to be looking for ways to react to orientation changes?

Comment: Nop, i just need to be notified when the height of the content of my webview changes. Note that it could happend after an orientation change because the width changes.

Answer (score 0):

Um, yes, [onresize](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/resize.html) (for the window, but still..) unless there is more than meets the eye to your question?
There are problems on iPhone though, but onscroll seems to [fire instead](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html).

Comment: body.onresize is triggered when the borwser window size changes. I need to be notified when body.scrollHeight changes. The page is displayed in a iphone/android webview. When body.scrollHeight changes, i have to resize my webView to fit.